# python boto3 uploaded file not visible

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, file-upload, boto3

I have the below code to upload a file to S3

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id="key here",
                      aws_secret_access_key="secere here",
                      aws_session_token="token here")
#Uploade the file
with open("/tmp/test.csv", 'rb') as data:
     result=client.put_object(Body=data, Bucket=bucket_name, Key="path/test.csv")
print(result) 
# Read the object
obj=client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key="path/test.csv")
j = obj['Body'].read()
print(j)
```

This code works fine and I'm able to read the file contents from S3 as shown above. The problem is when I do `aws s3 ls` from CLI the file is not visible and when I try to copy it says `fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "key here /test.csv" does not exist`. Similarly, when I check through AWS console I can not see the file. But when I write a separate code only to read the file it is available and prints the contents correctly.

I checked if the `aws region is correct` it is correct and I don't see file in any region. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Can you show full aws cli commands that you are trying to use?

Comment: @Marcin `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/key/test.csv` The credentials used is the same in both the cases

Comment: The command in itself is fine. So the issue must be with using wrong bucket, key, region or account. You have to double check these.

Comment: Also if you go to AWS console, you can't find the object there as well?

Comment: @Marcin yes that is correct

Comment: Is it regular bucket? Maybe you have some automation that deletes or moves new objects?

Comment: it is a normal bucket, when I upload the same file through CLI I can see the file

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. My problem was that I was using key incorrectly. My code:

```
bucket.upload_file(filepath, '/my/path/on/aws/foo.txt')
```

and I was not able to find the key on console or using aws cli as below.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/my/path/on/aws/foo.txt
```

However, using the same key I used to upload in separate code worked. Notice that the key starts with '/' which was the cause of the issue.

PS: I noticed that the code you shared here doen't have that issue, but it would be a good idea to verify it if you are generating key programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the credentials, even though the credentials worked from the local box it was giving the above problem, after switching to the credentials present in the CI/CD server it worked fine